# Include query result on separate line using SELECT CASE or similar

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, case

I would like to include my queries on separate lines using SELECT CASE. Instead of having Field, Tape Capture Value and Tape Value repeated on the same row, it would be great to have it on a separate line. Could someone please help with this? Thanks if you can!

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT T.[Loan Identifier], TC.Reviewer, 

    'Valuation Date' AS [Field],
    CASE 
    WHEN TC.[Valuation Date] <> T.[Valuation Date] THEN TC.[Valuation Date] END AS [Tape Capture Value], T.[Valuation Date] AS [Tape Value],

    'Underwriter name' AS [Field],
    CASE 
    WHEN TC.[Underwriter name] <> T.[Underwriter name] THEN TC.[Underwriter name] END AS [Tape Capture Value], T.[Valuation Date] AS [Tape Value]

FROM   [dbo].[Tape] AS T 
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Tape Capture] AS TC 
          ON T.[Loan Identifier] = TC.[Loan Identifier] 
TC.Reviewer IS NOT NULL AND TC.[Primary_review_complete?] = 1
```

Instead of having my result in its current form:

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z06f.png)

I would like it in the below form:

[Required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPAWW.png)

Comment: A case expression isn't going to help you here. Probably the simplest approach is to split this into two queries (one for tape value and one for tape capture). Then use a UNION ALL to merge them into a single result set. If you can create a sqlfiddle with some data we can help.

Comment: Hi Sean. I have built an sqlfiddle using Gorodon's advice. However I am still not able to return multiple columns. Are you able to help? Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d94ea/1. Thanks

Comment: Your sample data in your fiddle doesn't match the images you posted. What do you expect for output from your sql fiddle. BTW, the answer the Gordon posted just has a small syntax issue with the table valued constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is probably `outer apply`:

```
SELECT T.[Loan Identifier], TC.Reviewer, v.*
FROM [dbo].[Tape] T LEFT JOIN
     [dbo].[Tape Capture] TC 
     ON T.[Loan Identifier] = TC.[Loan Identifier]  OUTER APPLY
     (VALUES ('Valuation Date', CASE WHEN TC.[Valuation Date] <> T.[Valuation Date] THEN TC.[Valuation Date] END, NULL)
             ('Underwriter name', NULL, CASE WHEN TC.[Underwriter name] <> T.[Underwriter name] THEN TC.[Underwriter name] END)
     ) as v(field, [Tape Capture Value], [Tape Value])
WHERE TC.Reviewer IS NOT NULL AND TC.[Primary_review_complete?] = 1
```

Oops.  Instead of the table value constructor, use `select` with `union all`:

```
SELECT T.[Loan Identifier], TC.[Underwriter name], v.*
FROM [dbo].[Tape] T LEFT JOIN
     [dbo].[Tape Capture] TC 
     ON T.[Loan Identifier] = TC.[Loan Identifier]  OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT 'Valuation Date', CASE WHEN TC.[Valuation Date] <> T.[Valuation Date] THEN TC.[Valuation Date] END, NULL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Underwriter name', NULL, CASE WHEN TC.[Underwriter name] <> T.[Underwriter name] THEN TC.[Underwriter name] END
     ) as v([field], [Tape Capture Value], [Tape Value])
```

The logic is demonstrated in the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d94ea/11), but it mah not be exaclty what you want.

Comment: Hi Gordon, if I'm correct then the OUTER APPLY is trying to join the two tables (Tape and Tape Capture) into one table. under two separate columns. For me, this doesn't seem to work. I get weird parenthesis errors (Incorrect syntax near '(', Expecting CONVERSATION). Could you please help me understand.

Comment: @ConradAddo . . . I think a typo caused that.

Comment: Hi Gordon thanks for the help so far. I can perform the above query using one columnname result, ([Tape Capture Value] or [Tape Capture]). However I have the issue of "'v' has fewer columns than were specified in the column list."

Comment: Hi Gordon. I have built an sqlfiddle. However I am still not able to return multiple columns. Are you able to help? Here is the fiddle: sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d94ea/1. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL and do the following:

**

```
SELECT T.[Loan Identifier], TC.Reviewer, 

    'Valuation Date' AS [Field],
    CASE 
    WHEN TC.[Valuation Date] <> T.[Valuation Date] THEN TC.[Valuation Date] END AS [Tape Capture Value], T.[Valuation Date] AS [Tape Value] 

FROM   [dbo].[Tape] AS T 
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Tape Capture] AS TC 
          ON T.[Loan Identifier] = TC.[Loan Identifier] 
TC.Reviewer IS NOT NULL AND TC.[Primary_review_complete?] = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT T.[Loan Identifier], TC.Reviewer, 

    'Underwriter name' AS [Field],
    CASE 
    WHEN TC.[Underwriter name] <> T.[Underwriter name] THEN TC.[Underwriter name] END AS [Tape Capture Value], T.[Valuation Date] AS [Tape Value]

FROM   [dbo].[Tape] AS T 
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Tape Capture] AS TC 
          ON T.[Loan Identifier] = TC.[Loan Identifier] 
TC.Reviewer IS NOT NULL AND TC.[Primary_review_complete?] = 1
```

**

Comment: Hi Kamran. Would this work for more that 2 columns? For instance, I have 30 columns.

Comment: Hi @user3881822 when you say 30 columns do you mean 30 difference [Field] entries?

Comment: Hi Kamran, yes there are 30 [Field] entries (columns) and ~700 rows.

Comment: so if I understand correctly then you would need 30 UNION all statements and this will become a bit ugly. I would look into Gordon Linoff's solution as you would only need to update the CASE statements within the OUTER APPLY. You would still need 30 CASE Satements. But I would be able to give you a better answer if I had some sample data from you. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Kamran. I have made an sqlfiddle using sample data. are you able to help? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d94ea/1. I receive an error saying that 'v' has fewer columns than were specified in the column list.

Comment: Hi @ConradAddo try writing your Query like so: SELECT  T.[Loan Identifier], v.*
FROM dbo.Tape T
LEFT JOIN
dbo.[Tape Capture] TC
ON T.[Loan Identifier] = TC.[Loan Identifier]
OUTER APPLY
(SELECT (CASE
             WHEN TC.[Valuation Date] <> T.[Valuation Date]
             THEN TC.[Valuation Date]
         END
        ) AS [Valuation Date] ,
        (CASE
             WHEN TC.[Underwriter name] <> T.[Underwriter name]
             THEN TC.[Underwriter name]
         END
        ) AS [Underwriter name]
) AS v
       ;

Comment: Also I noticed that your Second insert statement insets into the Tape table as well. Shouldn't it be inserting into Tape Capture?